# Jquery - Change text from label

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is the label, having text = Use 20 kms

using jquery i want to Replace  the text "20 Kms" with  10 kms"

I get the hand to label like this

```
 $("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']");
```

how can i do that...

Comment: `$("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").html('Use 10 kms');` . ;)

Comment: Note that as you haven't quoted any markup, everyone answering has assumed your label is empty other than text (because you list the `for` attribute in your selector) -- which for a label with a `for` attribute is the common case and they're probably right. Just be aware that calling `text` on the label will replace **everything** it contains. If you have other elements within it, they'll be removed.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").text("10 kms");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").text('use 10 kms');
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gmsQp/1/)

text:

> Description: Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.

Answer (score 2):

Why not include the word 'Use' and save having to do a replacement:

```
$("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").text('Use 10 kms');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
$("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").text($("label[for='applyDistanceSlab']").text().replace("20 Kms", "10 kms"));
```