# Asp.net MVC4 Jquery changing the label value from the text box

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)
<label id="BulkItem[' + i + ']_UnitPrice" for="BulkItem[' + i + '].UnitPrice">

    $('#Price').change(function () {
       $('#BulkItem[' + i-1 + ']_UnitPrice').val($(this).val());
    });
```

Here is the code above. I need to set the value for every label that dynamically added. i used jQuery to set the value, but it is not work.
Please anyone help...any error?

Comment: That just cannot work. model.Price is a single value, not an array, and you cannot use brackets in HTML element IDs. You can use underscores if you want, however they are not necessary. What exactly are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: The reason using the bracket is generate the different ID for each of the label. It still hv 3 field need to save into List and store in the Model.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to understand your problem with this small piece of code. What is `ì`, where did you set this variable. Is there a loop. What is your html code? Is your problem the setting of a labels text with jQuery or the problem that your event (`.change`) does not fire?

Comment: `var i = $('#Bulk_DiV p').size();`
`<div id=Bulk_DiV>...</div>`

Here is my code, the Div inside is `<input>` only.
My problem is the .change didnt not fire. The value enter in `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price)` will be same with the `<label id="BulkItem[' + i + ']_UnitPrice" for="BulkItem[' + i + '].UnitPrice">` here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you. Html-Markup do not support [] as values. Better use `.text()`  instead of `.val()` on labels to edit the text.

```
<label id="BulkItem' + i + '_UnitPrice" for="BulkItem' + i + '.UnitPrice">
$('#Price').change(function () {
   var priceValue = $(this).val();
   // why (i-1)?
   $('#BulkItem' + (i-1) + '_UnitPrice').text(priceValue);
});
```

Just another post describing text-change on labels: [Other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9803399/jquery-change-text-from-label)

Comment: (i-1) -> because the label is dynamically added, not hard code

Comment: @FirionRedfield: This was clear, but if your index is starting with 0 the result is -1 and there is no element with an index smaller than 0.

Comment: I get the size of the DIV `var i = $('#Bulk_DiV p').size();`

Comment: It return 1 i checked. So i-1 should be zero.